# R/Knitr/ggplot - set default line width for entire document

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know how to change the line with for the graph using the aes for geom_line, but that only adjusts the line for the individual graph it's bound to.

How can I specify a line with for the entire graph? In a way similar to how I can adjust the font size for the document for all graphs:

```
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 28))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am wrong, but I do not believe it is possible to do this in the way you request.

Comment: Font size can be done with `theme_set` and the `base_size` argument as in the question. OP is looking for analogous code for `geom_line` size.

Comment: I apologize. I hope to stand corrected on this, but I have never come across a way to do this. At any rate, it would be odd if it was possible manipulate `geom_line()` from `theme_set()` in this way.

Comment: Many themes do manipulate geoms, colors, etc. See, e.g., `ggthemes::theme_economist()`, but I'm not sure how to do it.